# How to pass extra parameters for in row edit/save action in free-jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, free-jqgrid

I have a jgrid and the code is below. I wish to send some extra parameters to the server when the save icon in each row is clicked. How to do this?

```
let colNames = ['Designation', 'No. of Resource(s) Required', 'Competence for Job', 'Skill of Resource', 'Time Required(in %)', 'From', 'To', 'Reason For Request', 'Assigned Person(s)', 'Current Role in Project', 'resource_type', 'Billing'];

    let colModel = [
        {name:'resource_designation', index:'resource_designation', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value:designation_options}, editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_resources_required', index:'resource_resources_required', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_competence_for_job', index:'resource_competence_for_job', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', search: false},
        {name:'resource_skill_of_resource', index:'resource_skill_of_resource', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', search: false},
        {name:'resource_percentage_time_required', index:'resource_percentage_time_required', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules:{required:true, integer: true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_duration_from', index:'resource_duration_from', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {
            dataInit: function(el){
                $(el).datepicker({
                    id: 'resource_duration_from',
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
                });
            }
        }, search: false},
        {name:'resource_duration_to', index:'resource_duration_to', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {
            dataInit: function(el){
            $(el).datepicker({
                id: "resource_duration_to",
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
            });
            }
        }, search: false},
        {name:'resource_reason_for_request', index:'resource_reason_for_request', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        //{name:'assigned_persons', index:'assigned_persons', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_assigned_persons', index:'resource_assigned_persons', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions:{value:assigned_persons}, editrules: {required: true},  search: false},
        //{name:'current_role', index:'current_role', resizeable:true, editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_current_role_in_project', index:'resource_current_role_in_project', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: designation_options}, editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_resource_type', index:'resource_resource_type', resizeable:true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {"Full Time": "Full Time", "Buffer": "Buffer", "Trainee": "Trainee"}}, editrules:{required:true}, search: false},
        {name:'resource_billing', index:'resource_billing', resizeable:true, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions: {value:{"Billable": "Billable", "Non-Billable": "Non-Billable"}}, search: false}
    ];


    let editparameters = {
            "keys" : false,
            "oneditfunc" : null,
            "successfunc" : null,
            "url" : location_url,
             "extraparam" : {"grid": "rsf_people"},
            "aftersavefunc" : null,
            "errorfunc": null,
            "afterrestorefunc" : null,
            "restoreAfterError" : true,
            "mtype" : "POST"
        };

    let parameters = {
               edit: true,
               editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
               add: true,
               addicon:"ui-icon-plus",
               save: true,
               saveicon:"ui-icon-disk",
               cancel: true,
               cancelicon:"ui-icon-cancel",
               //addParams : saveparameters,
               addParams : {addRowParams:{extraparam:{"grid":"rsf_people"}}},
               editParams : editparameters
            };





$("#rsf_people").jqGrid({
    url: location_url,
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {action: "get_saved_allocated_resources"},
    colNames:people_colNames,
    colModel:people_colModel,
    rowNum: 5,
    height:'auto',
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    pager: true,
    emptyrecords: " ",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    scrollOffset:0,
    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
    autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true },
    idPrefix: "g1_",
    autoencode: true,
    sortable: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pagerRightWidth: 150,
    editurl: location_url,
    afterAddRow: function () {
        recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
    },
    afterSetRow: function () {
        recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
    },
    afterDelRow: function () {
        recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
    },
    inlineEditing: {
        keys: true
    },
    formEditing: {
        width: 310,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        savekey: [true, 13]
    },
    loadonce: true,
    caption: "RSF People",
}).jqGrid("navGrid", {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false})
            .jqGrid("inlineNav", parameters)
            .jqGrid("filterToolbar");

/* To make grouped headers */
$("#rsf_people").jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: false,
    groupHeaders: [
        {startColumnName: 'duration_from', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Duration'},
    ]
});
```

And my grid looks like below,

[image: overall grid]

If you look at the image I have marked the inlinenav actions like add and edit in **green**. So these works well and I am able to pass extra parameters using the variable **parameters**.

But I want to pass those same extra parameters to the edit action marked in **red** rectangle in the picture. How can I do that?

To put it otherwise, when I click on the "+" icon in the **green** bottom area it adds a new row to the grid and also a save icon to the left side of the row[the action column]. If I fill the data and click on the save icon in the same row left side it doesn't pass the extra parameters to the server. How can I achieve this? I wish to pass extra parameters when the save[exists in each row - marked in **red** in image] icon is clicked  .

[image: rowwise save]

How to achieve this? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your code you want to send `grid=rsf_people` as extra data on saving of inline data in case of both "add" and "edit" operation. Currently you set `extraparam` only for `inlineNav`. So the extra data will be sent in case of usage "save" icon in navigation bar only and not in "action" formatter.

Free jqGrid supports `inlineEditing` parameter (see `inlineEditing: { keys: true }` in your code), which simplifies forwarding parameters to inline editing methods. I'd suggest you to use

```
inlineEditing: {
    extraparam: { grid: "rsf_people" },
    mtype: "POST",
    keys: true
}
```

It should solve your problem. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more details.