# How to get additional field values in free-jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, free-jqgrid

I have a jqgrid (similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354929/how-to-pass-extra-parameters-for-in-row-edit-save-action-in-free-jqgrid)) with many columns. One of the column is **status**. And this status column is a dropdown field. When a particular option is chosen, I wish to get additional data from the user. How can I do it?

My guess is,similar to  addRow action pop-up of navGrid, we should have some form hidden and when a particular **status* option is chosen that form has to come up.

But I don't know how to do it in free-jqgrid! Please help me.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem you may use the dataEvents option in editing - especially you can bind a onchange event where you will call your custom function to show your custom form when certain value is selected.

Comment: @TonyTomov, Thank you! by the way, is there any other better way to get such additional values in free-jqgrid?

Comment: IMHO you should always bind onchange event to check that your **status** field has a certain value.